# Show that for each $n \geq 2$, $Q_n $ is Hamiltonian

Tags: graph-theory

I know that $Q_n = Q_{n-1} \times K_2$. So I let $U=\{u_1,u_2,\dots, u_{n-1}\}$ be the set of vertices of the first copy of $Q_{n-1}$ and  $V=\{v_1,v_2,\dots, v_{n-1}\}$ be the set of vertices of the second copy of $Q_{n-1}$.

I think of proving this by induction

Base : $n=2$, $Q_2$ is a $C_4$ so it's certainly Hamiltonian

Inductive step: Assume $Q_k$ is Hamiltonian. Show $Q_{k+1}$ is Hamiltonian. I know that the Cartesian product of any 2 Hamiltonian graphs is another Hamiltonian. but $Q_{k+1}=Q_k \times K_2$ and $k_2$ isn't Hamiltonian.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do a Hamiltonian traversal of one copy of $Q_k$ except for the last edge (i.e. a Hamiltonian path, not cycle, through the first cube), then cross over to the second copy of $Q_k$ and traverse it in reverse order from the first copy, and then close the big cycle.

Comment: yes, I can see that path, but i'm not sure I know how to explain it to work in a general case.

Comment: You could label the vertices of $Q_k$ as $v_1,\dots,v_m$ in such a way that $v_1,\dots, v_m,v_1$ is a Hamiltonian cycle.  Then the vertices of $Q_{k+1}$ may be considered to be $(v_1,0), (v_1,1),\dots, (v_m,0), (v_m,1)$.  Then it should be straightforward to explicitly give the needed cycle.